# Bluetooth keeps disconnecting my headset

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, bluetooth

I have a headset that I use most of the day. For some reason, it, or the bluetooth service itself keeps disconnecting the device. Sometimes I can reconnect, but other times the bluetooth & other devices window will say unable to connect. Other times it will turn bluetooth off entirely, removed the toggle switch so you can't turn it back on. The ONLY thing that works is a reset, and even then sometimes the bluetooth will be off with the toggle missing and the only way to restart it is to do a shutdown.

Things I've tried. Checking for updates for both the headset and the bluetooth driver. Ending and restarting the bluetooth service in powershell, trying to locate the 'power management' property for the headset and all the bluetooth devices, none of which seem to have this tab.

The headset in question is from taotronic, and their support website is completely down, so I can't try getting another driver from there.

I'm at a loss. It happens multiple times a day. I'm thinking it's a power saving issue, as it seems to happen most, if I finish watching or listening to something in chrome, or if I start watching something else, such as new youtube video.

I'm using windown 10.0.19045

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If this happens after a long period of keyboard inactivity, experiment with an application such as Caffeine, https://www.ghacks.net/2008/07/27/use-caffeine-to-keep-your-pc-awake/, to emulate key presses.